# Google Sheets match multiple results

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of codes I need to match to cross reference across 2 sheets in a workbook.  Each entry can have multiple matches and the columns are fixed, because there is other data in between.

I have an [example sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_PtbrcpYUyzXBSsiVWeS_B0K2oylesyi8dCuwKq-B64/edit#gid=0).

which looks like this [Cross referencing between sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cObjw.png) "Sheet2" is the source, Sheet 1 Column F is the desired result
This has gone beyond my VLOOKUP skills

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet gives "You need permission." To best get help, please share your sample spreadsheet with "can edit" rights.

Comment: thanks @JPV I have an answer but need to add an "if empty" element or the formula assumes that all possible fruits fit the query

Answer (score 1):

Given the data structure in your screenshot:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER($A$10:$A$14, FIND(A2, $C$10:$C$14)))
```

What's happening here is:
In `F2` we try to find the fruit in A1 in the lists of Fruits the individuals like (The formula by itself only works as an array formula):

```
=FIND(A2, $C$10:$C$14)
```

The result of that is a list of numbers indicating the position of the matched fruits and errors.
In a boolean interpretation Errors are `FALSE` and numbers other than 0 are `TRUE`.
We use this property to filter the range of the names:

```
=FILTER($A$10:$A$14, FIND(A2, $C$10:$C$14))
```

Lastly we join the range together, with a comma and a space (See above)

Comment: Thanks @Robin - strange but this =JOIN(", ", FILTER(Sheet2!$B:$B, FIND(A2, Sheet2!$D:$D))) works, but this =JOIN(", ", FILTER(VET Module Codes!$B$1:$B$300, FIND(A1,VET Module Codes!$D$1:$D$300)))  gives a parse error, despite the tab name being copy pasted from the TAB to exclude possible error

Comment: AHA got it - a named sheet needs the ' ' but Sheet2 doesn't ... rookie error

Comment: BUT  what if the lookup is empty (not yet populated)  IFERROR is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to this problem looks like this

= (IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",JOIN(", ", FILTER('Named Sheet A'!$B:$B, FIND(A2, 'Named Sheet B'!$D:$D))))))

Part of my problem was in trying to use IFERROR on its own, and using an excel code ISEMPTY instead of ISBLANK

Answer (score 0):

this would be my solution..

```
=if(LEN(A2), JOIN(", ", FILTER('VET Module Codes'!$B:$B, regexmatch('VET Module Codes'!$D:$D, A2))),)
```

and filled down. This checks if there is a value in col A, before the lookup is done.